# Кодировка: инициалы отображаются вопросительными знаками

Tags: php

Есть код

```
class emp
{
    public function __construct($sur, $nam, $pat, $age = 30)
    {
        $this->sur = $sur;
        $this->nam = $nam;
        $this->pat = $pat;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "{$this->sur} {$this->nam[0]}. {$this->pat[0]}.";
    }
    public function __get($index)
    {
        return $this->$index;
    }

    public $sur;
    public $nam;
    private $pat;
}
```

Почему первая переменная отображается нормально, а инициалы переменных nam, pat отображаются вопросительными знаками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, строки `$nam` и `$pat` представлены в Юникоде. В нём на один символ могут приходиться по несколько байт. Конструкция `$nam[0]` вытаскивает не весь символ, а только первый его байт, отсюда проблема.

Comment: а как это исправить?

Comment: Для работы с многобайтными кодировками в PHP используются библиотеки [iconv][1] и [mb_sting][2]

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php
  [2]: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте нормально оформить вывод:

`public function toString() { 
  return "{".$this->sur."} {".$this->nam[0]."}. {".$this->pat[0]."}."; 
}`

Comment: не катит, у меня даже ошибка возникла когда сменил __toString на toString

Comment: @t0di, здесь совсем не имеется ввиду отображение скобок, синтаксис

    "{$this->sur} {$this->nam[0]}. {$this->pat[0]}."

используется для того, чтобы не писать

    $this->sur . " " . $this->nam[0] . ". " . $this->pat[0] . "."

Т.е. для того, чтобы отобразить свойство объекта в строке достаточно ограничить их фигурными строками.

@Роман Соколов, точно не помню, но вроде как для этих целей надо использовать [substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php), а не $this->nam[0]